# Make edges parallel

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, photography

I have a digital photography and I'd like to correct the angle of the edges of buildings so that they are parallel.

Since I'll rarely use the software, I don't want to spend money. The software should work on Windows 7 and 10 and without Internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShiftN](http://www.shiftn.de/) seems to be fine.

- it's gratis (LGPL)
- works from Windows 2000 to Windows 10
- it autodetecs lines in the images and makes them orthogonal

Oh, and the correct search term seems to be "Automatic correction of converging lines".